# Can the "initialData" property be used to write App Script parameters to a Stackdriver message?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-stackdriver

### Summary

Google suggests that App Script parameters (among other data) can be written to Stackdriver using a JSON object with a "initialData" property.
But it doesn't seem to work.

### Issue Example

[This Google page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) contains an example function that illustrates the different ways information can be written to Stackdriver.

An extract from their own code is below:

```
var parameters = {
  isValid: true,
  content: 'some string',
  timestamp: new Date()
};
console.log({message: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters});
```

When their App Script function is run it should write these parameter values into the Stackdriver log message.

But after it's run and Stackdriver is examined the message (example below) doesn't contain the parameter anywhere in it:

```
{
 insertId:  "s14ubwdkw81"  
 jsonPayload: {
  message:  "Function Input"   
  serviceContext: {
   service:  "AKfycbwcG7JGj9z-yomue0m_bOVdIVyFgDasdsasdsadngdCkk_l"
  }
 }
 labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/deployment_id:  "AKfycbwcG7JGj9z-yomue0m_bOVdsadsad7x7pHYngdCkk_l"   
  script.googleapis.com/process_id:  "EAEA1GOzkIp_aAfasdsadsadsazTnDWNA_ureP83_A8Agfr4IQ9pzSfRzfj1wnw8U_lCUUA4O9afoxyZuCCHYlB5ryBpu0LxfcibIITaoFqdbiVjprxDC5sVIXUAdpnQX3ud0-Xp8t9awJPH484YyeQRsassadZzksNSXYxl4VwcOw"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key:  "MtcDasfdsfsfsfsfsaduYD4VaIEGs0Nwta"   
  script.googleapis.com/user_key:  "ANbVsadsadasdadashbqPEennz6PO1tasdsadasdfsddg+PjGhPshrkLV1SGwofeIcgpw0"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-id-416855555555555555559030426/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-22T15:14:53.355673423Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name:  "measuringExecutionTime"
   invocation_type:  "editor"
   project_id:  "project-id-416855555555555530426"
  }
  type:  "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity:  "DEBUG"  
 timestamp:  "2019-05-22T15:14:52.844Z"  
}
```

I think this is a Stackdriver or App Script bug, but I wanted to make sure I hadn't made a mistake or missed something.  Any ideas?

### Update

Further investigation suggests it probably is a bug, because the same code in a Cloud Function does work as expected, Stackdriver extract below:

```
{
 insertId:  "000000-7e143986-76f1-5555-b167-8186214f7739"
 labels: {
  execution_id:  "o8r9555cli0j"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/my-project/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-16T10:34:26.503211511Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name:  "gcf_htp_function_name"    
   project_id:  "my-project"    
   region:  "us-central1"    
  }
  type:  "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 textPayload:  "{ message: 'Function Input',
  initialData: 
   { isValid: true,
     content: 'some string'}"  
 timestamp:  "2019-05-23T10:34:21.084Z"  
 trace:  "projects/my-project/traces/a4df23072bfef15269947eaecf3a8f44"  
}
```

Comment: It seems that the property of ``message`` in the object of ``jsonPayload`` might be the prepared key. So when ``console.log({foo: "bar"})`` is run, ``jsonPayload`` becomes ``jsonPayload: {message: "{foo=bar}", serviceContext: {…}}``. In this case, ``{foo: "bar"}`` is converted to the string value. And also, it seems that ``message`` cannot use the object as the value. I think that this might be the specification or a bug.

Comment: If you want to show ``initialData`` in ``jsonPayload``, how about modifying the property name of ``message`` like ``console.log({messageSample: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters})``? In this case, these object is converted to the string value like ``message:  "{messageSample=Function Input, initialData={isValid=true, content=some string, timestamp=###}}"``. I posted this as a comment, because I'm not sure whether this is the result you want. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the work around suggestion Tanaike.  I'm going to hold fire ans see if Google fix the bug though because I'd like the to keep the nice JSON presentation structure when the parameters are displayed in the log, i.e. like the Cloud Functions example I've added.

Comment: Thank you for replying. This is growing now. So I think that this issue might be resolved in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug.

Google fixed it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133278375